# MATLAB MySQL ODBC connection

Tags: mysql, matlab, odbc

What would be the ODBC equivalent of the following:

```
hconn = database('{schema name}','{username}','{password}',...
                      'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',...
                      'jdbc:mysql://{hostname}:{port}/{schema name}?...
                      useSSL=true&requireSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&');
```

I am using MATLAB's Database Toolbox Version 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to perform a traditional connection to the database specifying the ODBC data source name (`ODBC DB` for example):

```
conn = database('ODBC DB','myuser','mypass');
```

If you want to use `Windows Authentication` instead, all you have to do is to specify the authenticated ODBC data source name (`ODBC DB AUTH` for example) and provide blank username and password:

```
conn = database('ODBC DB AUTH','','');
```

Refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-windows.html#bt8kjyk-3) for more information.